# Arquivos Statics

Tags: php, jquery, css, desempenho

Alguém sabe como usar os arquivos `statics` para melhorar o desempenho e velocidade do site?

Como os grandes ecoomerces usam:

```
static1.netshoes.net/resources/lind/netshoes/lindd.min.js
static1.netshoes.net/3470.1.1/assets/css-min/theme-common/structure.css
http://static1.netshoes.net/Produtos/88/N03-0046-188/N03-0046-188_zoom1.jpg?resize=74:74
```

Eles usam em imagens,scripts e css.

Alguém sabe a forma correta de se utilizar essa técnica?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro é preciso saber porque existe melhoria de performance ao utilizar o `subdominio.site.com`.

Acredito que as vantagens são:

1. CDN:

   O `static.site.com` está em um outro servidor, provavelmente um CDN, especifico para distribuir este tipo de conteúdo estático, o cliente irá conectar no servidor mais próximo.

   Enquanto que o `www.site.com` ainda é processado pelo *lento* PHP por exemplo.
2. Evita cookie e cabeçalhos desnecessários:

   Arquivos estáticos não ligam para cookie, em situações normais. Se você tem 500 bytes de cookies armazenados em todo o dominio e tenha 10 conteúdos estáticos que precisem ser carregados, o cliente vai enviar 5000 bytes adicionais, sem qualquer motivo para isso.

   Agora, se tais 500 bytes de cookie sejam restritos para `www.site.com` ele não será enviado quando for obter o `static.site.com/js.js`, [que vai poupar o envio de 5000 bytes de informações sem necessidade.](https://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/03/01/performance-research-part-3/)

   Isto inclusive faz parte do ["Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site"](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free).

---

Para que ganhe alguma performance usando `sub.dominio.com` é preciso que defina as cookies para apenas o site principal, sem incluir o subdomínio, além disso poderá contratar algum serviço de CDN para ele.